# what does >> and 1* means in this groovy statement?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I am working on grails/groovy project and while reading their test documentation came across this line of code

```
1 * myService.prova() >> { true }
```

I am unable to understand what does 1 * means here also as >> is right shift operator what does it mean here ?  I have searched so much but unable to get any proper explanation.
[Grails Test Documenation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is not groovy per se, but the testing framework called Spock (which is very popular among Groovy developers, for good reasons :-) - http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/index.html

This expression in particular is a way to instruct Spock that it should expect exactly one call to the method `prova` in `myService`, and that this call should be mocked to return `true`. See [Interaction based testing](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html) , in particular the section called *Combining Mocking and Stubbing*.

Comment: The link in my response (http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/index.html) is pretty exhaustive regarding mocking with Spock. There's also https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html#mockingCollaborators which refers to the same guide (link seems to be broken ATM). In the Grails guide you can also find how to mock using meta-programming, but I'd try to stick to Spock if that's what you are already using.